# Beta Multiplier Reference: What is going on with the current output?

Tags: current, cmos, voltage-reference

I have been working on a beta multiplier reference circuit using a 0.35um CMOS process. The circuit was previously designed and tested for a 0.7um process, but otherwise there have been no changes to the implementation. The circuit has no input, only a nominal supply voltage VDD of 3.3V and an output current I which is the drain current of transistor M1 (Fig. 1).

The circuit was simulated with a DC sweep of supply voltage VDD. For a supply-independent reference, what's expected is a current response with a generally flat profile from 3-10V (Fig. 2). Instead, the simulation shows a sudden increase of I at VDD ~5V (Fig. 3).

Any thoughts on what exactly is the cause of this current behaviour? I have tried scaling the linewidth of devices as well as fiddled with W/L ratios, but the "breakdown" at ~5V still remains, so I suspect the issue might be CMOS process-related.

Device dimensions, W/L (um/um):

M1 : 160/40

M2 : 40/40

M3 & M4 : 2/10

[image: Fig. 1: Schematic]

[image: Fig. 2: Expected response to DC sweep]

[image: Fig. 3: Simulation response to DC sweep]

Comment: 2 thoughts. Is your 0.35um process tolerant of voltages above 5V? Also, is M1_1 connected correctly? From the schematic it looks like there is a floating wire there.

Comment: It is true that the 0.35um process I am using has an absolute max Vds of 5V, but cross-probing the MOSFETs shows that the voltage drop across each of them is much lower than that value at the "breakdown" point.

Besides, the transistors have dimensions larger than 0.35um , so that should help raise the breakdown voltage right? Do you think it could be something to do with punch-through/channel length modulation?

Comment: Sorry about the floating wire, it was a drawing error and does not affect the  output in any way. I have fixed the image.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to you. Yes, I think some sort of punch-through or breakdown is very likely. I've posted some thoughts as an answer (since that are quite long!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's certainly possible that exceeding the maximum \$V_{ds}\$ is causing the problem. I guess non minimum length transistors would help, but I don't know by how much (could be checked in simulation). I've done some simulations that suggest that \$V_{ds}\$ might be the cause, and should provide a way to check too.

I assume your simulations are based on the BSIM3V3 model (or some BSIM variant). If that's so, it has a parameter called PSCBE1, which has an effect on breakdown voltage. Obviously, the correct values and effect of this parameter will vary by process. For the transistor models I have, the effect of varying this parameter from 1e8 to 5e8 is as shown below.

[image: MOSFET Breakdown Voltage Graph]

I set up a similar Beta Multiplier to yours (not the same, a simpler one based on that in Baker's CMOS Circuit Design, Layout and Simulation). It's shown below. The 3 extra transistors to the right are just a start up circuit.

[image: Beta Multiplier Schematic]

If I set PSCBE1 to 4.24e8, I get this response, which you can see is very similar to yours (it was a transient simulation, so I include a plot of VDD to show how it was being increased).

[image]

However, if I increase PSCBE1 to 7e8, I get this response.

[image]

You can see that the breakdown has moved up and off the graph. It's not a guarantee that \$V_{ds}\$ breakdown is the problem, but it certainly seems it is possible. One way to check might be to edit PSCBE1 in your own models and see if your problem goes away. Obviously, this means that your models then don't match your process, so you won't be able to to manufacture the device. In that case, you'll just have to accept that the voltage range is limited in your new process. Of course, if it has no effect, then this explanation is wrong and it must be something else!

Comment: Thanks for the reply @sobremesa. Yes, I am using the BSIM3v3 transistor model for this simulation. After discussing this with my (university) supervisor, he agreed that maximum Vds is likely the issue and that we'll just have to accept that.

Comment: Just to add, another supervisor suggested that it might be partly due to gate oxide leakage. The CMOS process being used (C35B4C3) has a typical gate oxide thickness of 7.6nm, whereas the design in Fig. 2 (which was from a similar project but based on a 0.7um process) had a gate oxide thickness of 17nm.